# Sleeping for an exact duration

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, real-time

My understanding of the Sleep function is that it follows "at least semantics" i.e. sleep(5) will guarantee that the thread sleeps for 5 seconds, but it may remain blocked for more than 5 seconds depending on other factors. Is there a way to sleep for exactly a specified time period (without busy waiting).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: "without busy waiting" <- you can't even do it with busy waiting. Your thread may be interrupted while waiting. (Maybe some real-time Windows priority could be useful)

Comment: Define "exact". Even with hand coded assembler attached to a hardware interrupt you're going to have effects due to cache misses and even waiting for the instruction pipeline to clear and refill. Even with busy looping you're going to be off by microseconds. What's "exact"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have said, you really need to use a real-time OS to try and achieve this.  Precise software timing is quite tricky.

However... although not perfect, **you can get a LOT better results than "normal" by simply boosting the priority of the process that needs better timing**.  In Windows you can achieve this with the [`SetPriorityClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686219(v=vs.85).aspx) function.  If you set the priority to the highest level (`REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS: 0x00000100`) you'll get *much* better timing results.  Again - this will not be perfect like you are asking for, though.

This is also likely possible on other platforms than Windows, but I've never had reason to do it so haven't tested it.

EDIT:  As per the comment by Andy T, if your app is multi-threaded you also need to watch out for the priority assigned to the threads.  For Windows this is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

Some background...

A while back I used `SetPriorityClass` to boost the priority on an application where I was doing real-time analysis of high-speed video and I could NOT miss a frame.  Frames were arriving to the pc at a *very* regular (driven by external framegrabber HW) frequency of 300 frames per second (fps), which fired a HW interrupt on every frame which I then serviced.  Since timing was very important, I collected a lot of stats on the interrupt timing (using [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) stuff) to see how bad the situation really was, and was appalled at the resulting distributions.  I don't have the stats handy, but basically Windows was servicing the interrupt whenever it felt like it when run at normal priority.  The histograms were very messy, with the stdev being wider than my ~3ms period.  Frequently I would have gigantic gaps of 200 ms or greater in the interrupt servicing (recall that the interrupt fired roughly every 3 ms)!!  ie: HW interrupts are FAR from exact!  You're stuck with what the OS decides to do for you.

However - when I discovered the `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` setting and benchmarked with that priority, it was *significantly* better and the service interval distribution was extremely tight.  I could run 10 minutes of 300 fps and not miss a single frame.  Measured interrupt servicing periods were pretty much exactly 1/300 s with a tight distribution.

Also - try and minimize the other things the OS is doing to help improve the odds of your timing working better in the app where it matters.  eg: no background video transcoding or disk de-fragging or anything while your trying to get precision timing with other code!!

In summary:

1. If you really need this, go with a real time OS
2. If you can't use a real-time OS (impossible or impractical), boosting your process priority will likely improve your timing by a lot, as it did for me
3. HW interrupts won't do it... the OS still needs to decide to service them!
4. Make sure that you don't have a lot of other processes running that are competing for OS attention
5. If timing is really important to you, do some testing.  Although getting code to run *exactly* when you want it to is not very easy, measuring this deviation is quite easy.  The high performance counters in PCs (what you get with QueryPerformanceCounter) are extremely good.

Since it may be helpful (although a bit off topic), here's a small class I wrote a long time ago for using the high performance counters on a Windows machine.  It may be useful for your testing:

**CHiResTimer.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

class CHiResTimer
{
private:
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER startCounts;
    double ConvertCountsToSeconds(LONGLONG Counts);
public:
    CHiResTimer(); // constructor
    void ResetTimer(void);
    double GetElapsedTime_s(void);
};
```

**CHiResTimer.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CHiResTimer.h"

double CHiResTimer::ConvertCountsToSeconds(LONGLONG Counts)
{
    return ((double)Counts / (double)frequency.QuadPart) ;
}

CHiResTimer::CHiResTimer()
{
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCounts); // starts the timer right away
}

void CHiResTimer::ResetTimer()
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startCounts); // reset the reference counter
}

double CHiResTimer::GetElapsedTime_s()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER countsNow;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&countsNow);
    return ConvertCountsToSeconds(countsNow.QuadPart - startCounts.QuadPart);
}
```

Comment: Awesome story and plenty of code provided too :) pity I've only got +1 to give.

Comment: and if the program is multithreaded, you need to specify high priority for sleeping thread too

Comment: I just recently had to try doing 120hz on Windows, and yeah this is not fun at all.  I tried something similar to your code, and it should be mentioned that running this code will max out one core of your CPU because it will never sleep.  If it did sleep, you're sleeping for no less than ~15.6ms.

Answer (score 5):

No.

The reason it's "at least semantics" is because that after those 5 seconds some other thread may be busy.

Every thread gets a time slice from the Operating System. The Operating System controls the order in which the threads are run.

When you put a thread to sleep, the OS puts the thread in a waiting list, and when the timer is over the operating system "Wakes" the thread.
This means that the thread is added back to the active threads list, but it isn't guaranteed that t will be added in first place. (What if 100 threads need to be awaken in that specific second ? Who will go first ?)

Answer (score 4):

While standard Linux is not a realtime operating system, the kernel developers pay close attention to how long a high priority process would remain starved while kernel locks are held. Thus, a stock Linux kernel is usually good enough for many soft-realtime applications.

You can schedule your process as a realtime task with the `sched_setscheduler(2)` call, using either `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`. The two have slight differences in semantics, but it may be enough to know that a `SCHED_RR` task will eventually relinquish the processor to another task of the same priority due to time slices, while a `SCHED_FIFO` task will only relinquish the CPU to another task of the same priority due to blocking I/O or an explicit call to `sched_yield(2)`.

Be careful when using realtime scheduled tasks; as they always take priority over standard tasks, you can easily find yourself coding an infinite loop that never relinquishes the CPU and blocks admins from using `ssh` to kill the process. So it might not hurt to run an `sshd` at a higher realtime priority, at least until you're sure you've fixed the worst bugs.

There are variants of Linux available that have been worked on to provide hard-realtime guarantees. [RTLinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux) has [commercial support](http://www.novell.com/products/realtime/); [Xenomai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenomai) and [RTAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTAI) are competing implementations of realtime extensions for Linux, but I know nothing else about them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you try to tackle a difficult problem, and achieving **exact** timing is not feasible: **the best you can do** is to use [hardware interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), and the implementation will depend on both your underlying hardware, and your operating system (namely, you will need [a real-time operating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), which most regular desktop OS are not). What is your exact target platform?

Answer (score 2):

As previous answerers said: there is no way to be exact (some suggested realtime-os or hardware interrupts and even those are not *exact*). I think what you are looking for is something that is just more precise than the sleep() function and you find that depending on your OS in e.g. the Windows Sleep() function or under GNU the nanosleep() function.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx
>
> http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_445.html

Both will give you precision within a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because you're always depending on the OS to handle waking up threads at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sleep for a specified time period using standard C. You will need, at minimum, a 3rd party library which provides greater granularity, and you might also need a special operating system kernel such as the real-time Linux kernels.

For instance, here is a [discussion of how close you can come on Win32 systems](http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/FAQS/timing.html).

This is not a C question.