# How to use irq0 and the PIT in x86 Linux to run a callback a given frequency?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, timer, x86

As far as I remember PIT (timer whose irq is 0) emits interrupt 16 or 18 times per second. This frequency (16 or 18 Hz) is just what I need for my application (it should emulate some physical device). Also, as far as I know irq 0 is used for task scheduler and it is triggered much more frequently than 18 Hz.

So, my question is: which is right? 18Hz or *much more frequent*? Another question is: is it ok to set my own irq 0 handler to be called after task scheduler (set handler with `request_irq` function)?

Comment: Are you writing a kernel driver, or userland? Userland question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923885/execute-a-method-every-x-seconds-in-c

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 I have an idea for some kind of emulator. The emulator will allow to study some procedures. I'm already aware of POSIX timers but I'd like to not use it. The PIT frequency is just what I would need to perform my calculus in interrupt handler. The userland process will only need to do some arrangements/rearrangements on some very hierarchical cross-refernced data structure.