# Sampling Loop coded in C is inaccurate

Tags: c, time

I have a piece of code which I am using to create a sampling loop with high accuracy. It is in c and runs in raspberry pi 3.

The sampling loop specifies 5ms and is printing 5ms. But occasionally, I am seeing number other than 5ms printed on the terminal. It does not happen often, but it is still a crucial issue to my application.

Attached is a video of what I am saying. It happen around the 40 seconds mark.

Sampling Loop Occassionally show number other than 5ms:
https://youtu.be/SNcLf3Zg3_I?t=40

I would like to get some help to debug the issue. Is there something wrong with the code?

The code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/time.h>

#define DT 0.005  //5ms

int mymillis();
int timeval_subtract(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *t2, struct timeval *t1);

int main() {

int startInt = mymillis();
struct  timeval tvBegin, tvEnd, tvDiff;

gettimeofday(&tvBegin, NULL);

while (1)
{
    startInt = mymillis();

    //Each loop should be at least 5ms.
    while (mymillis() - startInt < (DT * 1000))
    {
        usleep(100);
    }

    printf("Loop Time %d\n", mymillis() - startInt);
}

return 0;
}

int mymillis()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
}

int timeval_subtract(struct timeval *result, struct timeval *t2, struct timeval *t1)
{
    long int diff = (t2->tv_usec + 1000000 * t2->tv_sec) - (t1->tv_usec + 1000000 * t1->tv_sec);
    result->tv_sec = diff / 1000000;
    result->tv_usec = diff % 1000000;
    return (diff<0);
}
```

`

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`man usleep` specifies:

> The  usleep() function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds.  The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.

There's no guarantee that the sleep will last exactly that longer. Even less can it be guaranteed that the two time samples taken with usleep in between will stand at exactly 5ms distance from one another.

Additionally you might sample the lengths of 5ms valued-runs to see if oversleeps happen randomly which would probably finally close the case.

Comment: Hi bipll, I am not really sure how to fix it. Is there any alternative to usleep()?

Comment: @D.Bryan One thing you might try is storing the time, sleeping for slightly less than 5ms, then waiting in an idle loop until the elapsed time is close enough to 5ms.

Comment: @Davislor Probably even notably less than 5 ms, say each 500 microseconds. Still enough to have some sleep and granular enough to try not to miss the alarm clock. But after all we're not safe against one last sleep lasting 10ms rather than 500us. :-\

Comment: Hi bipll and Davislor, i had read through both your comment a number of times. But is still not getting it. Is there an example which you would show me to illustrate the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have forgot that that is exactly what you do (sleep for 100us then check if we need to sleep more), so please disregard my comment. Have you tried to sleep for longer amounts, btw? Does `usleep(2500)` or even `usleep(5000)` (or `usleep(4500)` then busy wait) make it any better?

Comment: Hi bipll, I just tried it. Using a longer sleep time, does not improve the situation but instead made it even worst. Is there any other solution? I need close to 5ms most of the time because i need my sensor data for my kalman filter to run every 5ms. I realise if I change my DT from 5ms to 10ms or 20ms, the same problem is still there.

Comment: Few suggestions can be found e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209408/sleeping-for-an-exact-duration
In brief: make sure you're using realtime scheduling; otherwise boosting thread's priority might help.